# Reordering rows of several arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider three matrices `X1`, `X2`, `X3` in Matlab of dimension `Nx(N-1)` listing some integers among `0,1,...,10`.

I want to reorder the elements in each row of `X1`, `X2`, `X3` wrto `X1`, **then** `X2` **(if some elements of `X1` are equal)**, **then** `X3` (**if some elements of `X2` are equal)** in ascending order.

**Example 1**

```
N=3;
X1=[3 8;
    7 7;
    2 1];

X2=[10 1;
    10 9;
    4 4];


X3=[1 1;
    1 0;
    1 0];

%I want to obtain
X1new=[3 8;
       7 7;
       1 2];

X2new=[10 1;
       9 10;
       4 4];

X3new=[1 1;
       0 1;
       0 1];
```

**Example 2**

```
N=4;
X1=[3 8 9;
    7 6 6;
    2 1 4;
    4 4 4];

X2=[10 1 2;
    9  10 10;
    4 4 5;
    5 5 2];


X3=[1 1 1;
    0 0 1;
    1 0 0;
    0 0 0];


%I want to obtain
X1new=[3 8 9;
       6 6 7;
       1 2 4;
       4 4 4];

X2new=[10 1 2;
       10 10 9;
       4 4 5;
       2 5 5];

X3new=[1 1 1;
       0 1 0;
       0 1 0;
       0 0 0];
```

This code does what I want. Could you suggest more efficient alternatives (if any) for cases in which `size(Y,1)` is large?

```
% 1) Create a 3d matrix Y of dimension Nx(N-1)x3
Y=NaN(N,N-1,3);
Y(:,:,1)=X1;
Y(:,:,2)=X2;
Y(:,:,3)=X3;

% 2) Reorder elements in each row (independently) 
     %wrto Y(:,:,1), then Y(:,:,2), then Y(:,:,3) in ascending order.
     %Store everything in Ynew of dimension Nx(N-1)x3 
Ynew = NaN(N,N-1,3);
for h = 1:size(Y,1),
    Ynew (h,:,:) = sortrows(squeeze(Y(h,:,:)), [1 2 3]);
end

% 3) Create X1new, X2new, X3new
X1new=Ynew(:,:,1);
X2new=Ynew(:,:,2);
X3new=Ynew(:,:,3);
```

Comment: Should `X2new` be `[1 10;9 10; 4 4]` instead of `[10 1;9 10; 4 4]`?

Comment: @Steve No, I reorder `X2` only if some elements in `X1` are equal.

Comment: I still don't really get what you mean. Maybe you could step through your example.

Comment: As your process is sequential (check x1, then x2,...) I think that you can't linearize your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the numbers are between `0` and `10`, you can easily combine the three matrices into one for the purposes of sorting (step 1); sort each row of the combined matrix and get the indices of that sorting (step 2); and from that build a linear index (step 3) which you can use into the original matrices (step 4):

```
M = 11; % Strict upper bound on possible values
Y = X1 + X2/M + X3/M^2; % STEP 1: combined matrix
[~, cols] = sort(Y, 2); % STEP 2: sort each row and get indices of sorting
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (1:size(X1,1)).', (cols-1)*size(X1,1)); % STEP 3: linear index
X1new = X1(ind); % STEP 4: result
X2new = X2(ind);
X3new = X3(ind);
```

Answer (score -3):

sort(X,2) will do this. The 2 is to do it row-wise.

Comment: This does not do what I want, it is not a simple sorting.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the condition where you only want to do this if row elements are equal. Question: What if the row has 3 elements? For instance:

    A = [3 2 1; 1 1 2; 1 2 3];

In the second row, there are two ones. Does this mean that A gets sorted? Or do you want to have all elements equal before A gets sorted (so only if A would be 

    A = [3 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 2 3];

Comment: See my example with `N=4`

Answer (score -3):

It can be done simply by using 
['sort' command in Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)

```
X1new = sort(X1,2);
X2new = sort(X2,2);
X3new = sort(X3,2);
```

Comment: This does not do what I want, it is not a simple sorting.